# Agrupar SQL por campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo los siguientes datos en una tabla, necesito agrupar por "grupos" del campo U_entregas, necesito que agrupe cada que detecte un grupo diferente, es decir, en el siguiente ejemplo muestra los primeros 2 registros en 0, necesito que se agrupen esos 2 y muestre la fecha mas antigua, luego continúe con los números 2 y muestre la fecha mas antigua de esa agrupación, luego agrupe los numero 3 y después agrupe los números 2 de nuevo pero no en la primera agrupación de numero 2 y así sucesivamente.

**La tabla es:**

```
UpdateDate/U_Entrega/UpdateTS 

2021-08-17/ 0 / 165458 

2021-08-17/ 0 / 165534 

2021-10-28/ 2 / 121425 

2021-10-28/ 2 / 122802 

2021-10-28/ 2 / 122825 

2021-10-28/ 2 / 122925 

2021-10-28/ 3 / 122945 

2021-10-28/ 3 / 122959 

2021-10-28/ 3 / 134413 

2021-11-04/ 3 / 95207 

2021-11-04/ 2 / 101059 

2022-01-04/ 2 / 175444 

2022-01-05/ 2 / 141023 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 154301 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 154313 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 162335 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 162829 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 163106 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 163415
```

**y necesito que el resultado sea :**

```
UpdateDate/U_Entrega/UpdateTS 

2021-08-17/ 0 / 165458 

2021-10-28/ 2 / 121425 

2021-10-28/ 3 / 122945 

2021-11-04/ 2 / 101059 

2022-01-05/ 3 / 154301
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues esto funciona:

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [U_Entrega] ORDER BY UpdateDate, U_Entrega DESC) rn
FROM datos)


SELECT
  [UpdateDate], [U_Entrega], [UpdateTS]
FROM (SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [U_Entrega], rn ORDER BY UpdateDate, U_Entrega DESC) rn2
  FROM cte) a
WHERE rn2 = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

El único ajuste que se debe realizar es genera una columna auto incrementable para tener como referencia.

Un ejemplo funcional en este fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec9ba/2

A continuacion el resultado que se obtiene:

```
| UpdateDate | U_Entrega | UpdateTS |
|------------|-----------|----------|
| 2021-08-17 |         0 |   165458 |
| 2021-10-28 |         2 |   121425 |
| 2021-10-28 |         3 |   122945 |
| 2021-11-04 |         2 |   101059 |
| 2022-01-05 |         3 |   154301 |
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375588/row-number-partitioning-according-to-consecutive-rows

Comment: Quizá deberías de [Crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Uno de los problemas que tiene la pregunta, es que se basa en un orden, y en código TSQL, quizá ese orden no sea como esperas. [Order by](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Fíjate en el primer punto de la documentación. `El orden en que se devuelven las filas en un conjunto de resultados no se puede garantizar, a menos que se especifique una cláusula ORDER BY.`

Comment: Modificada la respuesta con el ejemplo :)

Comment: Culpa mía. Evidentemente lo que has hecho mejora la respuesta, pero no lo había escrito por tú respuesta sino, por la pregunta. El comentario era para el autor. Con la información facilitada la respuesta es en mi opinión encomiable. Tiene muchísimo más trabajo, la respuesta que la pregunta, cuando debiera de ser al revés. Pero esa columna identitaria es clave para buscar un resultado adecuado. Puede ser que no exista o que sea de otro modo, y la solución puede ser diferente. No obstante, yo al menos te doy las gracias, por el esfuerzo.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí lo que buscas, sería agrupar por `UpdateDate` y `U_Entrega` y obtener el valor mínimo de `UpdateTS`, algo así:

```
SELECT UpdateDate,
       U_Entrega,
       MIN(UpdateTS) as 'UpdateTS'
       FROM tu_tabla
       GROUP BY UpdateDate,
                U_Entrega
```